# Choice of token (fungible or non-fungible) pertaining to modifiability of information stored

Tags: blockchain

Suppose that I have a list of information to be stored in a blockchain and I would like certain parts of the information previously updated by the previous owner to be unmodified. The new owner of the token can only modify parts which he or she is allowed to. Which token would be suitable for such application? (Example given below)

Based on what I have read, non-fungible tokens are suitable for unique data like digital arts and cannot be tampered with.

I would like to seek clarifications pertaining to the below doubts:

1. Can the owner of the NFT modify information on the NFT after creating it? Or can the information on an NFT only be written once?
2. Can subsequent buyers of the same NFT append new information on the NFT?

An example of the situation for which I must choose a suitable token type:
Identification of asset: XJJHAKS1972 (unmodified) 
Current policy coverage of asset: In-forced (not in-forced) (modifiable by current owner)
Period of coverage: 2021 to 2022 (modifiable by current owner)

History of ownership:
Ownership 1: Mr XJHGAK(unmodified)
Dates of ownership: 1st January 2019 to 6th June 2019(unmodified)

Ownership 2: Mrs JHHUA(unmodified)
Duration of ownership: 7th June 2019 to 6th June 2020(unmodified)

Ownership 3: Mr Bee
Duration of ownership: 7th June 2020 (modifiable by current owner)

---

History of residency of asset:
Country: Country A (unmodified)
Date: 1st January 2019 to 6th June 2019 (unmodified)

Country: Country B (unmodified)
Date : 7th June 2019 to 6th June 2020 (unmodified)

Country: Country C (modifiable by current owner)
Date : 7th June 2020 (end date not indicated which indicates that the asset is still in country C to date.) (modifiable by current owner)

Comment: I think I have the same question. For example, a game item called "Armor" sold from A to B. Can B change its color before selling it to C?

Answer (score 1):

> *1. Can the owner of the NFT modify information on the NFT after creating it? Or can the information on an NFT only be written once?*
>
> *2. Can subsequent buyers of the same NFT append new information on the NFT?*

Answer to both questions is: **It depends on your implementation.**

Token standards (e.g. [ERC-721](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-721.md)) only define an interface and few other rules (such as when to emit events). How to implement the interface, that's up to you.

---

An example that validates whether the sender is current owner of the token. And only if they are, the contract allows the change:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.3;

contract Test {
    mapping (uint256 => address) tokenIdToOwner;
    
    function changeCountry(uint256 _tokenId, string _country) external {
        require(tokenIdToOwner[_tokenId] == msg.sender, 'Only current owner can change it');
        // TODO rest of your implementation
    }
}
```